# Add Heart Rate and Calories Burnt from a Polar Monitor to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

For the past little while, I've been building a product for my personal training clients that allows me to quantify all their data into Google Sheets. As of now, the Google Sheets is being used as a proof of concept for a future app to go along with my training studios.

The issue I'm trying to solve currently, and I hope I'm using the correct lingo is -

**Can I add a line of code to add Heart Rate Tracking and Calories Burnt from a Polar Heart Rate Monitor (or any other heart rate device) into the client's daily workout?**

Below you can see what the sheet looks like. I track all my client's strength and conditioning metrics (and heart rate/calories burnt on the Ipad), however, I'm trying to consolidate it all into one place.

[image: Client's workout "tab"]

[Gym set-up with Airplay, Sheets, and Whiteboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh1DC.jpg)

Comment: If you want google sheets why tag it Excel and not Google Sheets?

Comment: I was so focused on asking a well-articulated question, I kept forgetting that I use Google Sheets now, and not Excel lol. Thanks for the edit. Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of what is the expected result?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: The expected result would be: 

- The client is wearing a heart rate strap on the chest or arm 
- The data from the Polar Heart Rate strap is inputted into the "Heart Rate" and "Calories Burnt" section of the Google Sheets, rather than using the Polar App.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think I'm answering my own question. It probably isn't possible since Polar probably wouldn't allow it to be synced elsewhere... 

If anyone has any thoughts on another way to consolidate this information into my Google Sheets, that would be great. 

I hope I'm explaining myself correctly. 

Cheers!

Comment: Not so fast @MattGolt. I can't see this happening in real-time, but it seems to me that you're thinking about by-passing the Polar device altogether. From what I can gather there are a number of Polar devices that use PC/Mac-based software, and some/all?? allow data to be exported. So if the device will "sync" to a PC, then I think you'll find it will export data as a CSV (or similar); in which case you _could_ pull it into Google Sheets.

Comment: @Tedinoz First off, thanks for taking the time. It's great you understand the question - and even made it more clear for me. 

It needs to be in real-time. My clients love it - and it's a great building block for a future app and such. 

Picture this, the clients see their workouts on my TV screen, from Apple Airplay, and not only do they have their exercises, sets, reps... on there, but their heart rate and calories burnt too (in real-time), without having to host another app to see it (the Polar one). 

Gonna share picture of my set-up.

Comment: Added the gym set-up picture above. "Gym set-up with Airplay, Sheets, and Whiteboard". Stack didn't allow me to show the whole picture because I'm new.